# Winexe error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE executing script from Linux to Windows Server 2012

Tags: networking, server, bash, scripts, samba

I've installed winexe on my linux machine. I want to use it to execute some script on a Windows Servre 2012. It doesn't work, the error is NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE.

I've followed this guide to install winexe: https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Winexe

I've enabled SMBv1 and SMBv2 on Windows Server. The script I'm trying to execute is:

./bin/winexe -U administrator%pwd4administrator //serverip "cmd.exe" I've done nothing else. Am i missing something?

The workgroup on my linux machine (on /etc/samba/smb.conf.) is "MYGROUP", the workgroup on Windows server is "WORKGROUP". I tryed this way:

./bin/winexe -U administrator%pwd4administrator -W WORKGROUP //serverip "cmd.exe" But nothing changed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: I'll second that

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written does not appear to have anything to do with the operation of the Ubuntu OS. You might be better served reviewing similar issues over on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site. Best of luck.

Comment: I vote to keep the question open. Winexe is a Samba command: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/winexe.1.html :`winexe allows remote command execution on native Windows operating systems.` He even references the /etc/samba/smb.conf file in his question.

Comment: You stated that you enabled SMB1 on the Windows server. Did you also enable SMB1 on the Ubuntu client? You need to add to the [global] section of smb.conf the following directive: `client min protocol = NT1` That's an N T one.

Comment: This question is on topic and it shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Running [OpenSSH for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui) on your Windows machine, might be a better option?

```
luuk@mint:~$ ssh luuk@windows "dir c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
luuk@windows's password: 
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0A26-7955

 Directory of c:\windows\system32

03-05-2023  21:04           323.584 cmd.exe
               1 File(s)        323.584 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  91.448.864.768 bytes free
luuk@mint:~$
```

NOTE: I added a line in `/etc/hosts` like `192.168.0.11 windows` to make Linux know where my Windows machine is. You can also use the ip-address in stead of the name.